# Buffer ring problem with uses of make feature layer

Tags: arcpy, error-000210

Im trying to create a buffer ring shape but gets me the error 210:

> arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 000210: Cannot create output
>   C:\Trabajo Carto\TempPrograma\"capa de Ringbuff70".shp Failed to
>   execute (Dissolve).
>
> Failed to execute (MultipleRingBuffer).

```
with open (nombarch3) as p:
for x in recortes2:
    dtaring = p.readline()
    arquet, valbuf2, datperm= dta.split(",")
    valbuf2=float(valbuf2)
    a= valbuf2*0.3
    b= valbuf2*0.5
    c= valbuf2
    distances = [a,b,c]
    c=str(x)
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(outsal,'"capa de Ringbuff'+x+'"')
    arcpy.MultipleRingBuffer_analysis(outsal,'"capa de Ringbuff'+x+'"', distances, "meters", "", "ALL")
p.close
first = True
entrada = []
for x in recortes2:
    if not first:
        entrada=entrada+","+ '"capa de Ringbuff'+x+'"'
    else:
        first = False
        entrada='"capa de Ringbuff'+x+'"'
arcpy.Merge_management(entrada,bufferRings)
```

Comment: Spaces are forbidden in file names by the shapefile specification (and bad practice in general). What happens if you use underscores?

Comment: Spaces are forbidden in feature classes names but not in shp names. But I totally agree that it a bad practice to use them :)

Comment: No, the [shapefile specification](http://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf) *does* actually require "8.3" naming (Naming Conventions, pg 2) -- it's just not enforced as it ought to be.

Comment: OK... forbidden but possible. Not the cause of the issue here anyway

Answer (score 1):

The 000210 error code is [documented](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00vp0000000n000210.htm) with:

> 000210 : Cannot create output
>
> Description
>
> The output cannot be created. Potential reasons include data locking,
>   an incorrect path, and limited access rights.
>
> Solution
>
> Confirm that the data is not locked by another user or application and
>   that you have full rights to the workspace being used. Check to make
>   sure that the path to the data is correct (check for typos in the
>   folder path). Try creating the output in a new location.

Given that you are trying to embed spaces in the file name (which is not best practice), and that the error message **includes the quotes in the file name**, I'd guess that ArcGIS is just forwarding an operating system error for attempting to name a file with embedded quotes.

If you use underscores to eliminate the spaces in the name, the quotes won't be necessary. If you insist on spaces in the name, put one set of quotes around the whole string or use a Python file-naming function for assistance.

Comment: i will try ASAP without the spaces and posted what appends.

But without the quotes python will not recognize the name as a variable?

Comment: `"capa_de_Ringbuff"+str(x)`

Comment: I already try this, and get:


arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000732: Input Datasets: Dataset capadeRingbuff70,capadeRingbuff74,capadeRingbuff80,capadeRingbuff132,capadeRingbuff142,capadeRingbuff143,capadeRingbuff144,capadeRingbuff145,capadeRingbuff146,capadeRingbuff147,capadeRingbuff148,capadeRingbuff149,capadeRingbuff150 does not exist or is not supported
Failed to execute (Merge).

so idk if there is a problem with the makefeaturemanagement? But i dont want to have a lot of shps in each pass...

Comment: This is a Python coding issue, a different problem at a different location. You should post the changed code as a different question. It would help if you add some diagnostic print lines, and include the output in your question (you might even be able to solve it yourself)